# Create a Private cloud using IIS

Tags: wcf, iis, azure, routes, cloud

I have a WCF service running in IIS. It uses a SQL database instance. I need to go to cloud. I am currently in Beta testing.

Azure seems to be expensive. I paid $150 for two months for azure without doing much access.

Is it possible to run the IIS at my home server and create a private cloud, so i could use it from anywhere outside.

Is there any links that would tell me how to do this?

Comment: I hosted my account in AWS. It looks cheaper and is free for one year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my solution. I hosted WCF on AWS. It was a bit complicated but its cheaper and is free for one year.

Answer (score -2):

Why don't you get a "simple" hostingprovider to setup a windowsmachine with IIS? This setup won't be expensive.

Just google on hosting & windows.

Regards, Tim

Comment: This in no way answers OP's question. `This setup won't be expensive` is subjective. `why dont you get a "simple" hosting provider` is totally unclear as to what that is supposed to mean and the coup de grace `just google`.  I'm sure that you are genuinely trying to help, but please post answers contain facts.

Comment: Can you give an example. I need a SQL database instance as well. I would prefer to host it from my home and publish it initialy.